# Spring Boot application is not running in STS with profiles due to Run Configuration is not showing Project names in Drop Down to be selected

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, microservices, spring-tool-suite, git-clone

Need some help in running Spring Boot Application, I have cloned a Microservice and Imported into Eclipse. Now I want to run this as spring boot application in my STS(4.10.0 version). While running I need to supply profile. For this I am setting up configuration (Run Configuration).
Steps :

1. Right click on Project
2. Select Run As > Run  Configurations
3. Select "Spring Boot App" -> Click to Add new Configurations
4. Here I am unable to select Project, it is not displayed in drop down. Below is screenshot
   [image]

Note : I tried Importing Project as "Maven Project", "Existing project Into Workspace" and Git project into workspace. All these 3 ways are not working for me

Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like your project is not recognized as a Spring Boot application. Without looking at your project it is hard to say why the IDE doesn't identify your project as a Spring Boot project. Does that work when you create a new Spring Boot project using the Spring wizards? Also feel free to share a link to your project, we would be happy to take a deeper look.

As a workaround, you can always start your Spring Boot application as a regular Java Application using the "Run as Java Application" in the IDE. That way you would have to set the active profiles via a system property in your launch config.

Comment: Martin, this is what I feel might be not identified as spring boot project by STS. I am not creating any new project. In fact a functional Spring boot service I am cloning and importing into my STS.  Outside STS I am able to build and run with maven but using STS , I am not able to do so  :(

Comment: Sounds like the best way to debug this would be to raise an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and share your project there, so that we can take a deeper look.

Comment: Hi Martin , thanks for the suggestion, It is resolved now. Issue was that My project is not identified as SpringBoot project by eclipse. And to ensure that I required to update my classpath file with certain entries. And now I refreshed it, then it is taken as Spring Boot project by STS.

Comment: Great, glad to hear that you resolved the issue and thanks for sharing the solution here.

Comment: @Neeraj Can you tell how did you do that

Comment: Hi @NirodhaWickramarathna,  their is issue with .classpath file with package structure . I corrected my file with package details in classpathentry tag . And later on it started identifying

Comment: Hi @Neeraj and Nirodha, I am stuck at same level where my project is not able to run as Spring boot project. I have cloned this application from Github after long time, earlier it is used to run the simply by pulling > updating > Run as > Maven Clean install > Spring boot dashboard > Run/Debug
Now, I am not able to perform the last step since Project is not visible under Spring Boot Dashboard section. This is my build path, Could you please give your advice on it.

Comment: Hi @Videsh , I suggest you to please check .classpath file in your local springBoot service.  There your need to check your src path and other relevant details. To me after correcting I was able to see my application as SpringBoot file

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, I had this issue for a spring boot maven project and it was `pom.xml` being malformed even with no warning or error. Took me days, I had imported/re-imported/messed with the java build path/compiler and installed jres. I was unable to download `maven dependencies`. I took a look in the `dependencies` section of the `pom.xml` and noticed `lifecycle-mappings` issue. Once I took out the 3 lines of incorrect xml syntax in the `pom.xml` I was able to download the maven dependencies and then the project appeared as a spring boot project in run configs.